# Sharing location using Whatsapp from my application

Tags: android, android-intent, location, whatsapp

In one of my applications,I am passing latitude and logitude from my app to whatsapp and want to share that location.I achieved it using this piece of code.

```
public void sendMessage() {
    String whatsAppMessage = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, whatsAppMessage);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Everything is fine since it is giving me location card from google maps and I am able to share the same.But I just wanna know,is there anyway so that I can share location like how whatsapp do it by default.I mean the card which Whatsapp uses.Please Check the screen shot for clear understanding.[image].
Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.